# Twitter Bootstrap manually close tabs 

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, href

### **UPDATE WORKING NOW**

Got it working now. Script snippet was wrong and was not even called somehow.

For future reference -> to close bootstrap tabs:

```
</script>
$("#closetab").click(function() {
$("#myTabContent").hide();
});
</script>


<a href="#" id="closetab">Close</a>
```

And be careful when using center-TAGs for anchor texts. It screws with your js/jquery when pointing to IDs of content within the center TAG.

---

Im using Bootstrap Tabs ( http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs ) with a slightly changed bootstrap-tab.js to show tabs on hover:

```
  $(function () {
$('body').on('hover.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"]', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
})
```

Now i want to add a way to manually close those tabs. I found a code snippet somewhere that does the trick in Chrome/Mozilla/Opera **but not in IE:**

```
<script>
$('a[href="#closetab"]').on('click',function(){
$("#flyout_tab").hide();
});
</script>
```

and

```
<a href="" id="closetab">Close</a>
```

In IE when i click the close-button it sends me to the root of the directoy the site is in.

I guess it has something to do with the way IE handles empty a href's (a href=""). When i put something like a href="#" it wont work in any browser.

Comment: What was the original question?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting "closetab" in the href property like this:

```
<a href="#closetab">Close</a>
```

Since the above code doesn't work, try changing the script to:

```
<script>
    $('#closetab').on('click',function(){
        $("#flyout_tab").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nope , im not sure if i get what you mean but if i put it like you suggested im obviously getting to an Error 404-Page :)

Comment: My mistake, I missed the hash in front

Comment: Yea i already thought you missed that and tried it. Not working. Thats just an anchor link to itself. No hiding/closing of the tab.

Comment: Its like once the href is not empty the javascript is not even called. Is there maybe something wrong with the script itself? Im pretty clueless when it comes to js/jquery..

Comment: Have you tried putting an alert method in the body of the click handler to see if the event is getting triggered?

Comment: Did that now. The script isnt even called. The tab did not close because of the script but just because an empty link was called.

Comment: Question is now why a simple alert script doesnt work either?

Comment: One thing that's wrong for sure is the selector for that link. I'm wondering why it's working for other browsers. Try changing the selector to the one I added in my answer.

Comment: Its working now. Stupid center tags screwed with the IDs of the anchor. Script wasnt even called because of that. See my question-edit for working code. Thank you anyway!